# my react-native project is not debug mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

My `react-native` project is not on development mode.

Double tab R key is not working, and `cmd + M` not working..

My another project is connect to `localhost:8081`, but my project not connect to `localhost:8081` but, build is success.

help me!!

nothing error.

Answer (score 5):

You can run the packager on another port.

```
react-native start --port=8088
```

you can also try this

```
 $ adb reconnect
```

This is not necessary in most cases, but just in case, let's reset your connection with your mobile and restart adb server. Finally:

```
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then run this command

```
$ fuser 8081/tcp
```

You will get a Process id which is using port 8081 Now kill the process

```
$ kill <pid>
```

Then run the project`react-native run-android`

Comment: i do that but it does not work...